# Generic assertThat(ArrayList, hasItems(InstanceOfSomeInterface)) not working

Tags: java, generics, junit, hamcrest

i want to use Hamcrest’s `hasItems` with an "actual" collection that is an `ArrayList<? extends SomeInterface>`
on

```
assertThat(ArrayList<? extends SomeInterface>, hasItems(InstanceOfSomeInterface))
```

the compiler says:

> The method `assertThat(T, Matcher<T>)` in the type `Assert` is not applicable for the arguments `(ArrayList<capture#9-of ? extends MyInterface>, Matcher<Iterable<MyInterface>>)`

what is going wrong? What can i do about that (i really want to use Hamcrest here)?

Comment: Can you post the code showing the types of the collection?

Comment: my collection is of type <? extends IsTreeItem>:
`private ArrayList<? extends IsTreeItem> filteredAdminUnits;`
and this i want to use like this 
`assertThat(filteredAdminUnits, hasItems(anTreeItem))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ArrayList<SomeInterface> newList = new ArrayList<SomeInterface>();
newList.addAll(origList);
assertThat(newList, hasItems(InstanceOfSomeInterface));
```

It is unfortunate that Assert.assertThat was not coded using **? super** or **? extends** to allow for what you describe.